# Is it a problem for BPs to talk to Relays using different versions of cardano-node?

Tags: stake-pool

If my BP is running cardano node 1.30.1 and I just upgraded one of my relays to cardano-node 1.31.0, will they still be able to talk to each other or will all nodes have to be updated?

Comment: I was actually wondering this same thing and was going to test it. I believe they should be fine for between these 2 versions but not sure if that holds true for other different versions. I'll post my results as an answer after I test it (for 1.30.1 BP and 1.31.0 relay).

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out! They can talk to each other. And yea I believe for soft forks like 1.30.1 -> 1.31.0 they are fully compatible.

The issue turned out to be a silly loopback error. My mistake!